# Position element in centre of visible viewport window with overflow-y:scroll

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, scrolltop

I've rather roughly built this website which uses an effect similar to the iOS Safari tab view to look at various pages of a virtual book. Everything is working fine apart from the fact that I can't centre each page in the visible viewport. For example if you scroll down to the final 'page' and click on it, it jumps to the top of the document, instead of staying in the centre of the visible viewport.

I think this is to do with the fact that the scrollable div uses overflow-y:scroll, but I just can't figure out for the life of me how to fix the problem.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!!

Here's my jQuery:

```
jQuery(document.body).on('click', '.page', function() { //Change to touchstart

// Generate number between 1 + 2
var randomClass = 3;
var randomNumber = Math.round(Math.random() * (randomClass - 1)) + 1;

// Initialise & Random Number
jQuery(this).addClass("activated").addClass('scaled-' + randomNumber);

// Exiting - Reset All
jQuery(document.body).on('click', '.activated', function() { //Change to Touchstart
  jQuery(this).removeClass("activated scaled-1 scaled-2 scaled-3");
});
});
```

And here is a jsfiddle with all my code in it so you can get a better idea of what I'm trying to achieve.

https://jsfiddle.net/ontu1ngq/

Thanks!

Comment: Try removing the `top` value from `activated` ... https://jsfiddle.net/ontu1ngq/1/

Comment: Hi @DanielPinzon, thanks for your feedback! Removing the top value from activated kinda works but then if you click on one of the 'pages' and it's not quite fully in the window, then it displays half out of the visible window if that makes sense?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to get the amount that `#wrapper` has been scrolled, so that you can use that to set the `top` of the `.page` accordingly. Then, when you remove the `.activated` class, you will just need to remove the inline `top` style.

```
jQuery(document.body).on('click', '.page', function() { 
    var randomClass = 3;
    var randomNumber = Math.round(Math.random() * (randomClass - 1)) + 1;
    jQuery(this).addClass("activated").addClass('scaled-' + randomNumber);

    var wrapper_scrollTop = $("#wrapper").scrollTop(); //gets amount scrolled
    var half_wrapper = $("#wrapper").height()*(0.5); //50% of wrapper height
    jQuery(this).css("top",half_wrapper+wrapper_scrollTop);

    jQuery(document.body).on('click', '.activated', function() { 
        jQuery(this).removeClass("activated scaled-1 scaled-2 scaled-3");
        jQuery(this).css("top","") //returns top to original value specified in css
    });
});
```

Check out this working fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/tardhepc/1/